# Handle Exceptions with tasks

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task

Say that I have code like this:

```
serviceCallFinished = false;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    response = ServiceManager.GeneralService.ServiceMethod(loginName, password);
}).ContinueWith(parentTask => { serviceCallFinished = true; });

while (!serviceCallFinished)
    Thread.Sleep(100);

if (response.UserValid) { }
```

In this case the `ServiceMethod` will throw a `Exception` but this is never shown, instead I will get a null reference on the `response.UserValid`?

Why is the exception not handed over to my UI thread?

Note : This is on the UI thread and my idea is to not block the thread during the servicecall.

Comment: It does not reply your question, but please remove that loop for waiting the completion. use something else ( manualResetEvent )

Comment: The main thread here is a UI thread and it can´t be blocked, this is why I use Tread.Sleep. I do also not want to split the method up to be able to send the thread to a specific method.

Comment: if the purpose of thet loop is non blocking you are definitely wrong: the UI thread is blocked doing sleep.

Comment: okay, so the only way to solve this is to split up the method and then in the ContinueWith pass the thread on to the second part of the method(method2)? This will be alot of methods and do the code vary complex.

Comment: the Joe reply is the one to use both for correct waiting and exception management

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a flag like that just to wait for an async task to finish. Use Wait()

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    response = ServiceManager.GeneralService.ServiceMethod(loginName, password);
});

try
{
    t.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
   ...
}
```

the Wait() call will elevate any exceptions within an overall AggregateException.

Comment: As written, yes.  There are a multitude of overloads for .Wait that take a time parameter (int milliseconds, or a TimeSpan) and return true or false if the task didn't complete during that Wait cycle.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the comments and contrary to the example posted, it seems like you want logic that returns to the caller while a response is being awaited, and then do a bunch of stuff afterwards.  It also sounds like the stuff afterwards contains a lot of very complex methods that you want to write procedurally.  The C# team has heard your problem and many like it and developed the async/await framework that will do exactly that, slated for C# 5.  Alternatively, if it is an option for you, there is an AsyncCTP available here:  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9983  HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [How to: Handle Exceptions Thrown by Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614.aspx)
There is also a good sample.

Wha you could do is basically replace your sleeping loop with:

```
try
{
    task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write code just like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
  {
   response = ServiceManager.GeneralService.ServiceMethod(
     loginName, password);
  })
  .ContinueWith(parentTask => { if (response.UserValid) { } });
```

It seems more clear and more responsive.